# 2D interpolate function issue

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I'm trying to write an interpolation function to get any value of CO2 from a value of Ts and Seff. My grids of Ts and Seff are not square.
The issue is that for certain values of Ts (eg 275), Seff only goes from 0.4 to 0.8, while for other values of Ts (eg 320), Seff goes from 0.5 to 1.2.
But when interpolating, if I ask for a value of CO2 when (Ts=275, S=1.1), I get a value of CO2, even though I should just get NaN (as for Ts=275, Seff of 1.1 does not exist).

I tried to resolve this issue with the bounds_error and fill_value arguments below, but this only insures that I get a Nan value when interpolating outside the "absolute" maximum and minimum values of S.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

Seff =[0.88383316136305645,1.0298932275648676,1.1097533821426062,1.1234656716815736,0.80369957429646033,0.93326566449886517,1.0134725598796075,1.0452557986414284,0.71380176528610517,0.81469788653203512,0.89382224429581447,0.94761085313180471,0.40459228983422418,0.43388658896464499,0.46430015708333283,0.50080988488067069]

CO2 = [63.632000000000005,63.632000000000005,63.632000000000005,63.632000000000005,3171.6999999999998,3171.6999999999998,3171.6999999999998,3171.6999999999998,59829.0,59829.0,59829.0,59829.0,760870.0,760870.0,760870.0,760870.0]

Tslist = [275,290,305,320,275,290,305,320,275,290,305,320,275,290,305,320]


Tsnew = np.arange(280, 315, 0.001)
Seffnew = np.arange(0.5, 1.1, 0.001)
f=interpolate.interp2d(Tslist,Seff,CO2,bounds_error=False, fill_value='NaN')

print f(275,1.1)
>> array([ 70446.45005256])
```

But it seems to still be interpolating outside the bounds of each Ts. Is there a way to remedy this?

Comment: (This was an answer to a comment that was removed)

Sorry if this is unclear. Here, the 4 data values of Seff for Ts = 275 are (0.88383316136305645, 0.80369957429646033,0.71380176528610517,0.40459228983422418). So the bounds of Ts=275 are ~0.4 to 0.88.

Comment: You are experiencing issues because you have multiple values of Tslist that correspond to different values of Seff. This violates most interpolation functions since multiple values are valid for a given interp scheme. Hope that makes sense

Comment: My advice would be to assign an average value of Seff for a given value of Tslist and perform 2D interpolation on that data set. Your answers should be more reasonable.

Comment: You have non rectangular bounds which interp2d does not deal with. This is how the bounds are [calculated](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py#L295). So you could either change your basis to a rectangular grid or look for other interpolations.

Comment: @skmth Right... I checked other interpolation functions but it seems like they would all have the same issue. Do you have one in mind that would handle this?

Comment: Your desired interpolation is discontinuous right. I'd recommend writing your own boundary condition and applying it after the interpolation. Else you can add nan values in your input data and use scipy.interpolate.griddata, but then the interpolation could become volatile.